# Is it possible to find a separator in a vector using an iterator and addition / division?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a quick sort and I need to find an array separator in the algorithm:

```
template<typename Iter> 
void Q_sort(Iter left,Iter right) {
    auto separator = *(left + (left - right) / 2);
    auto t_left = left, t_right = right;
    while (t_left < t_right) {
        while (*t_left < separator) ++t_left;
        while (*t_right < separator) --t_right;
        if (t_left<=t_right) {
            std::swap(*t_left, *t_right);
            ++t_left;
            --t_right;
        }
        if (left < t_right) Q_sort(left, t_right + 1);
        if (t_left < right) Q_sort(t_left + 1, right);
    }
}
```

But when I pass iterators

```
std::vector<int> for_sort(10);
Q_sort(std::begin(for_sort),std::end(for_sort));
```

and try to find it through them, I get **Debug Assertion Failed**:
`Expression: cannot seek vector iterator before begin`

I thought maybe because of the fact that right points to a value beyond the boundaries of the vector but such a call:

```
Q_sort(std::begin(for_sort),std::end(for_sort)-1);
```

gives the same resul.Then I tried to write auxiliary functions

```
template <typename T,typename Alloc>
inline T* begin_ptr(std::vector<T, Alloc>& vec) {
    return vec.empty() ? nullptr : &vec[0];
}

template <typename T, typename Alloc>
inline T* end_ptr(std::vector<T, Alloc>& vec) {
    return vec.empty() ? nullptr :begin_ptr(vec)+vec.size();
}
```

But with such a call:

```
std::vector<int> for_sort(10);
Q_sort(begin_ptr(for_sort), end_ptr(for_sort)-1);
```

I get that with any random filling of the vector, separator is always equal to 1.I would be happy to help taht figure out what's wrong, thank you.

Comment: There are some issues with your algorithm. For example, the  recursive calls should not be inside the partitioning loop. Some of the `while` conditions seem wrong as well.

Comment: This line `while (*t_right < separator) --t_right;` with `t_right = right;` and `right` passed as `std::end(for_sort)` is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Also I think an initial test for the empty range and return would be useful.  There is quite a bit an analysis of subsequent code to see if it properly handles the empty range.  So a quick initial test and return makes my thinking easier.

Comment: @RichardCritten it doesn't work in both cases

Comment: @Omegon but maybe not for the same reason.  Fix the UB and add the empty range test and see what happens.

Comment: @RichardCritten "This line..." why? because right points out the border?

Comment: @Omegon `*t_right` is dereferencing the `end` iterator, when `right` is passed in as `std::end(for_sort)`

Comment: @RichardCritten but right must point to the end.if right change as right -1 then also doesn't work because of separator which is not found